# JBoss 7 EAP Application Specific Logging with Shared Modules

Tags: spring, jboss7.x

Maybe I am just completely missing something but I am trying to configure log4j in JBoss 7 EAP with the main goal of isloating application ( WAR ) log messages to unique files.

Our environment has Spring ( 3.X ) configured as a module, and each WAR ( let's call them WAR A and WAR B ) has its own jboss deployment descriptor for Spring as well as a log4j.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.springframework.spring" slot="3.2" meta-inf="export" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>


log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE
log4j.category.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/webapp_a.log
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-a
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d %-5p (%-6t) [%X{IP}] [%c] %m%n
```

Each application creates its own log files, however all the Spring logs are written to the JBoss server.log, and not the application specific log as I would expect. The idea is I would like to see only the spring logs that are relevant to the application in its log file

Am I missing something completely obvious, or really just not understanding how the classloading is working in JBoss 7 where this isn't even possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have Spring installed as a module. Modules log via the system log context which is configured via the logging subsystem.

Since the `org.springframework.spring` uses it's own class loader you really wouldn't want the `org.springframework.spring` module to log with an applications log context. The reason is any static loggers would be configured on whichever application configures the logger first.